# Why is my TStringList not sorted?

Tags: delphi, sorting

I have a custom sorted `TStringList`...

```
Items.CustomSort(@CompareWords);
```

... with this comparison function:

```
function CompareWords(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrIComp(PWideChar(List[Index1]), PWideChar(List[Index2]));
end;
```

But after noticing some problems with my code, which expects the list to be sorted in the order `StrIComp` induces, I created this small check...

```
for i := 1 to Items.Count - 1 do
begin
  Assert(StrIComp(PWideChar(Items[i-1]), PWideChar(Items[i])) <= 0);
end;
```

... and it fails.

**Why isn't the list sorted properly?**

Comment: 1. Which Delphi version are you using? (IOW: Is the cast of Items[I] to PWideChar valid?)
2. Why do you use StrIComp and not simply CompareText?
3. Is the result of calling Sort OK?

Comment: Yes, the cast is correct. I use the string list to prepare a binary file, which is later being binary-searched using StrLIComp. I feel better, when both parts use the same comparison method.

Comment: Do not use `@` before the function when you call `CustomSort`. It can mask errors in the declaration of your comparison function. (In this particular case, you're OK, though.) Also, please type-cast to `PChar`, not `PWideChar`. Just because they're the same type for you doesn't mean they'll always be the same type. `TStringList` holds generic strings, so type-cast to generic `PChar`. (Even if *you* never use a different Delphi version, others who come here to copy and paste your code might, so it's better not to use version-sensitive code when you don't have to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have Items.Sorted=True.

Comment: You nailed it :) Items.Sorted was true, obviously resulting in some weird behaviour. I also updated my question to remove the code mistakes you pointed out. Can you please rephrase your answer to just point to the Sorted property? Then I'll accept it.